# Which is the most secure way to send credentials to a login API from a SwiftUI mobile app?

Tags: php, api, security, swiftui

I hope you're all doing well. I was wondering what is the most secure way to communicate with a PHP login API to which I send credentials and get Json Web Token in case of a successful login ? Also, where should I store the JWT while the app is running ? Should I send the credentials in the body or the header ? should I encrypt it ?

I red in the Apple documentation that "ATS requires that HTTP connections use HTTPS", so I thought that using URLSession is a good and secure solution.
I'm quite new to SwiftUI and trying to learn what is the most secure way to communicate sensitive data to web API.
Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: 'where should I store the JWT while the app is running' should not be asked on this site you won't get a definitive answer as it's opinion based, this is one of a few questions in this post that is opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a POST over HTTPS and put the credentials into the POST body. For additional security you can do a challenge-response authentication where the API provides a challenge string, client adds the password to it, takes a SHA-256 or similar and sends back the hash to the API for login. But usually this is not necessary, HTTPS is trusted to be secure.

I would store the JWT in browser local storage but opinions seem to differ on this.